# Decoding utf-8 encoded string variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with decoding a utf-8 encoced string variable in python.

```
text = b'JAK SI\xc4\x98 \xe2\x80\x9eNAZYWA\xe2\x80\x9d?'

text.decode()
-> OK

text = str(text)
text.decode()
```

> Error:'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

I only have access to the string variables. How do I get a decode a utf-8 encoded text from a string variable? Thanks!

Comment: What language are you working in? Please add it to the tags

Comment: In Python 3, `bytes` objects have a decode method, and `str` objects do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> text = b'JAK SI\xc4\x98 \xe2\x80\x9eNAZYWA\xe2\x80\x9d?'
>>> text.decode()
'JAK SIĘ „NAZYWA”?'
>>> s = str(text)
"b'JAK SI\\xc4\\x98 \\xe2\\x80\\x9eNAZYWA\\xe2\\x80\\x9d?'"
>>> eval(s).decode()
'JAK SIĘ „NAZYWA”?'
```

Is this what you wanted?